# Android auto fade

Tags: android, screen, fade

I'm developing an application for android and I have a problem.

My application displays pages to read, but the android has the function to fade the screen to save battery, thus disturbing reading. I wonder if it is possible to change the fade time when the user is using the application, that will solve the problem.

Thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your app can certain acquire a wake lock and keep the screen on.

Read here for details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Options are:

```
SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
FULL_WAKE_LOCK
```

You should select one of the last two if you don't want the screen to dim (warning that the user should understand by you doing this it will consume lots more battery).

Comment: @ArturCouto No problem, the second part of the answer to "change the fade time" is to set an alarm manager timer to release the wake lock at a certain time you want (for example provide the user the ability to set how long they want to wait before dimming the screen/reverting to standard phone settings and then you can release the wake lock), of course if they leave your app release the wake lock.